# Array is undefined when trying to load data into Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, undefined

Im trying to load data into an array and just added soem console.log to test if it works.

```
reload(){
this.dataService.getPostoffice()
    .subscribe(data => this.poArray= data);

console.log(this.poArray);
```

}

Sadly the array is undefined at this point. I mean im filling the data into the array there but its still undefined. If I try to console.log that array later in the code its working fine and logs the full data of the array. Can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling the array asynchronously that is why the array is filled but you are not displaying it at a correct time.

```
reload(){
this.dataService.getPostoffice()
.subscribe(data => {
  this.poArray= data;
 console.log(this.poArray);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you nee to have the console inside the subscribe like the snippet below:

```
reload(){
 this.dataService.getPostoffice()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.poArray= data;
    console.log(this.poArray);
 });
}
```

Hope this helps.